# Error while trying to get data from the database for login

Tags: html, sql, asp.net, authentication

I have the below code that is supposed to return me a String (either with a value or empty) but instead I am getting the following text value inside the String result `"System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise 1[System.Object]"`because of which my call to `(String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))` gives an unexpected result.

```
private bool UserLogin(string un, string pw)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select username from CTM_DATABASE.dbo.users where username=@un and password=@pw", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@un", un);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", pw);
    con.Open();

    string result = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync());
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))  return false; return true;
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? 
PS: it is my first time coding in ASP.net

Comment: Use `cmd.ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: @Siyual thanks a lot. It worked.